# How to infer the type of an object's property

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have the following piece of code and I'd like to infer the type of an object's property. As you can see, the inferred type of `v` in my example is `{}`. 
How can I write `myValue` so that `C` is inferred at compile time by Typescript?

```js
const myValue = <T1, T2>(prop: string, obj: T1): T2 => {
  return obj[prop]
}

interface C {
  readonly c: string
}

interface TestInt {
  readonly a: string
  readonly b: number
  readonly c: C
}

const test: TestInt = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 1,
  c: {
    c: 'c',
  },
}

const v = myValue('c', test) // const v: {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type parameter inference works best when you have an actual value of the type you're trying to infer.  Having `T2` be the type of the return value of the function is likely to be a problem.  Unless you call `myValue()` in a context that *expects* the return value to be of type `C`, there is little hope that the compiler will infer `C` for it... inference of a type parameter from a return value is called [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing), and unfortunately in `const v = myValue(...)`, there is no contextual type for `v`.  It can be anything.

So what types do you actually have values of?  Since you call `myValue()` with `prop` and `obj` parameters, the first thing to try is to give `obj` a generic type like `T` and to give `prop` another generic type like `K`.... and infer `T` and `K` from `obj` and `prop` respectively.

Note that you intend that `prop` should be one of the keys of `obj`, so you have a natural [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) on the type of `K`, namely that it should extend `keyof T`.

Finally, the return type of your function can be derived from the other types.  It is meant to be the type of the property of `T` whose key is `K`.  That can be represented as `T[K]` (a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types)).

Here's the final version of the function:

```
const myValue = <T, K extends keyof T>(prop: K, obj: T): T[K] => {
    return obj[prop];
}
```

Note the similarity between that function and the `getProperty()` function mentioned in the [documentation for `keyof` and lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).  The only difference is the order of parameters (well, and the fact that the return type is inferred instead of annotated.... and the function name, I guess).

When we use that defintion of `myValue()`, we get:

```
interface C {
    readonly c: string
}

interface TestInt {
    readonly a: string
    readonly b: number
    readonly c: C
}

const test: TestInt = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 1,
    c: {
        c: 'c',
    },
}

const v = myValue('c', test) // const v: C
```

as you wanted.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Great answer! That helped for sure.

Comment: I was wondering..what if I want to currify myValue so that I can call it like myValue('a')(test)?

Comment: This seems like a different question, but the short answer is `const myValue = <K extends keyof any>(prop: K) => <T extends Record<K, any>>(obj: T): T[K] => obj[prop];`

Comment: Awesome thanks, I didn't expect this to rely on `any`. I guess I still have a lot to learn on typescript type inference.